Create 8 bit compressed RGB with Pillow
For my college project, I need to convert a 4-byte colored png file to a 1-byte colored png file using Keil.
I've converted a png file to a hex file using Python, then loaded a hex file in Keil, progressed the data, and got the output.
In Keil, a hex file with a 4-byte RGBA was changed to a 1-byte RGB(RRR_GGG_BB in each byte) by removing the alpha channel and concatenating 3 or 2 MSB of each color.
Compressing process MUST be done in keil.
So the output hex file has 1-byte RGB data.
I put this data in python, reshape the array, but I can't make it to PNG file.
Here's the code that I tried.
from intelhex import IntelHex
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

ih = IntelHex()
ih.loadhex('memoutput.hex')
pydict=ih.todict()
rgbcomp = np.fromiter(pydict.values(), dtype=int)
rgbcomp = np.reshape(rgbcomp,(640,960))
img_2 = Image.fromarray(rgbcomp, 'P')
# https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#modes
img_2.show()

Each data in rgbcomp array has 1-byte RGB data(R[7:5]+G[7:5]+B[7:6]).
Does anyone knows how to make reshaped array to 256 color PNG using pillow?
It should be look like true-color image converted into 256 color gif image.
Please help.
++ Added at 14:15, May 23, 2024
Here's the file of keil's output memoutput.hex
And also I've almost done that make pltePix - targetting the number of palette, plte - palette that decompose RRRGGGBB to R[7:0], G[7:0], B[7:0]
from intelhex import IntelHex
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

ih = IntelHex()
ih.loadhex('memoutput.hex')
pydict=ih.todict() #hex to dict
rgbcomp = np.fromiter(pydict.values(), dtype=int) #array of values in dict
uniqRgbComp = np.unique(rgbcomp) #int list of uniq colors
plte = np.zeros((len(uniqRgbComp),3)) #plte(24bit rgb) = uniqRgbComp(8bit rgb)
for i in range(len(uniqRgbComp)):
   plte[i] = np.array([ int(uniqRgbComp[i]&0b11100000), int( ((uniqRgbComp[i])&0b00011100) << 3 ), int( (uniqRgbComp[i]&0b00000011) << 6 ) ])
pltePix = np.zeros(len(rgbcomp)) #Pixel data points palette
for i in range(len(rgbcomp)):
    pltePix[i] = np.argwhere(uniqRgbComp==rgbcomp[i])[0]
pltePix = np.reshape(pltePix, (640, 960))

The last, I just need to write PNG file using pltePix(pixel data), and plte(palette).
Can I get help to write 1-byte RGB image with these two arrays?
The original image is:

The 256 color image will looks like(generated by photoshop, 3:3:2 color will looks different):

++ Added at 14:50, May 23, 2024
FINALLY I MADE IT!!! Thanks for your all help.
And the code:
from intelhex import IntelHex
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# data=[None]*256
# for i in range(256):
#     data[i] = i
    #data[i] = f'ob{i:08b}'

ih = IntelHex()
ih.loadhex('memoutput.hex')
pydict=ih.todict() #hex to dict
rgbcomp = np.fromiter(pydict.values(), dtype=int) #array of values in dict
uniqRgbComp = np.unique(rgbcomp) #int list of uniq colors
plte = np.zeros((len(uniqRgbComp),3)) #plte(24bit rgb) = uniqRgbComp(8bit rgb)
for i in range(len(uniqRgbComp)):
   plte[i] = np.array([ int(uniqRgbComp[i]&0b11100000), int( ((uniqRgbComp[i])&0b00011100) << 3 ), int( (uniqRgbComp[i]&0b00000011) << 6 ) ])
pltePix = np.zeros(len(rgbcomp)) #Pixel data points palette
for i in range(len(rgbcomp)):
    pltePix[i] = np.argwhere(uniqRgbComp==rgbcomp[i])[0]
pltePix = np.reshape(pltePix, (640, 960))
im = Image.new(mode="P", size=(960,640))

plte = np.ravel(plte)
plte = np.uint8(plte).tolist()
im.putpalette(plte, rawmode="RGB")
pltePix = np.ravel(pltePix)
im.putdata(pltePix)
im.show()

Output:


Image.fromarray(rgbcomp, 'P') -- with mode P, if you want colours, you will need to explicitly specify a palette (I think via putpalette member function). | What exactly does "I can't make it to PNG file" mean? Do you get some error, it doesn't look like expected, or what?

The output looks like weird grayscale image. I've added the original hex file and new codes. Thanks for help

Updated Answer
Thank you for providing your Intel hex file. I converted it to a straight binary file with just 61,4400 bytes (960*640) using:
objcopy --input-target=ihex --output-target=binary image.hex image.bin

objcopy should be in any compiler toolchain. I actually used Alpine Linux on docker and installed the binutils package to get it.
You can then do the following:

read the file into a Numpy array and reshape
convert to a PIL Image
create a palette, per my original answer
push palette into image and save


#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Convert your Intel hex file to 'image.bin' with:
# objcopy --input-target=ihex --output-target=binary image.hex image.bin

# Load binary file and reshape to 960x640
pixels = np.fromfile('image.bin', dtype=np.uint8).reshape((640,960))

# Make into 'PIL Image'
im = Image.fromarray(pixels)

# Generate palette
pal = [ [i & 0x70, (i & 0x1c)<<3, (i & 0x3)<<6] for i in range(256)]

# Flatten palette and push into image and save
flat = [x for xs in pal for x in xs]
im.putpalette(flat)
im.save('result.png')



Original Answer
You should really share your 1-byte RGB file so folks can test their solutions, but I'll try and answer blind.
You have 2 options:

read the 1-byte RGB file into Numpy, promote the colours to full RGB88, convert to PIL Image and let PIL deduce a palette for you
read the 1-byte RGB file and formulate a palette for it, and push that palette into the image.

I think the first option is not "in the spirit" of your assignment, so let's go with the second.

At each pixel location, you will have 1-byte, with a value in the range 0..255. You need to determine what RGB colour that byte must become in order to make a palette. Let's look at the first few:
0  => rgb(0,0,0)
1  => rgb(0,0,64)
2  => rgb(0,0,128)
3  => rgb(0,0,192)
4  => rgb(0,32,0)

So you need something like this to generate your palette.
pal = [ [i & 0x70, (i & 0x1c)<<3, (i & 0x3)<<6] for i in range(256)]

Then you'll need to call putpalette(pal) to force that palette into your P mode image.
All code sadly untested due to lack of input data in question.

I'd just add file "memoutput.hex" and made a code that targets pixel location, and palette.
How can I make PNG file in P mode using that two arrays?

You use Image.frombytes or Image.frombuffer to assign the pixel values, and then use the putpalette to assign the palette.  A 3:3:2 image isn't going to look very good.  There are no shades of gray at all, so most images look very bad.

It's not important to look good or not, since the main purpose of assignment is convert 32-bit RGBA to 8-bit RGB. Btw, thank you for your answer.

Thank you for the hex file. I have updated my answer - please have another look.
